# Edit redirect uri Request.js after login

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, requestjs

I'm using `request.js` and `cheerio.js` to scrape a password protected website.

Is it possible to edit the response uri such that I could scrape another page other than the one I'm being redirected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at using [`tough-cookie`](https://github.com/SalesforceEng/tough-cookie) in combination with `request.js`.

This should allow you to create a `cookie-jar` that stores your session on the password-protected websites and you can continue to request other pages whilst still appearing logged in.

Usage (from the `request.js` [examples](https://github.com/request/request#examples)):

```
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
```

Comment: Trying now, will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure: I've installed `tough-cookie`, and set `{jar: true}`. Then, after I log in (using a POST request) I'm sending a GET to another page on the site, and that's supposed to work? (it doesn't). Thanks!

Comment: @shikaka - I need more info than "it doesn't (work)" I'm afraid

Comment: it logs me out and when I print the scraped page it's the login page

Comment: There could be more at work than just a cookie then. You should follow the behaviour through your browser first then try to replicate in your program.

Comment: There was a minor problem other than that, thank you!